# Best practice for multiple SMPS-generated power rails at different voltages on PCB

Tags: pcb-design, switch-mode-power-supply

When creating a PCB design with multiple power rails at different voltages, all drive by switching power supplies, is it better to generate all of the voltages from a single input voltage, or two derive small voltages from other power rails? For instance, in my current project I have a 24V input, a 10V rail and a 3.3V rail. Would I be better off with a power supply that converts 24V to 10V, and 24V to 3.3V, or a power supply that converts 24V to 10V, and then 10V to 3.3V? The latter seems like it would offer some efficiency benefits at the cost of increased power supply transient noise.

Comment: Don't be so sure about those noise issues. Assume that noise (high) frequencies can pass straight through a converter in either direction between input and output. A regulator switching at 100kHz isn't going to react fast enough to do anything about a 50MHz transient.

Comment: Efficiency of conversion is never 100%.  2 to 30% losses are typical with a switched mode regulator.  Depending on how much loss you have in each converter and the load, the additional losses you have on your 3.3V rail could be anywhere from negligible to quite significant, so you should bear in mind if you cascade regulators, you compound your losses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends.

Let's just start by assuming that the ideal (or at least, most straightforward) way is to have a single converter for each output voltage straight from the raw voltage source. In that case, we run into beat frequencies if the converters do not have synchronized clocks and we have to deal with by using filters to stop high frequency noise from passing straight through the converters in either direction and contaminating each other.

But sometimes the voltage step is too large to be feasible in a single converter. In that case you might benefit form multiple cascaded converters to gradually step down the voltage. In this case again, you can have beat beat frequency and noise issues.

Or perhaps, the distance between the raw voltage source and the final load is large so you step it down a bit with an initial converter (and maybe use that to power other things as well), but keep the voltage relatively high to minimize currents and thus transmission losses and distribute it to converters closer at the load before stepping it down at the point-of-load (PoE).

Then there's other factors. For example, some regulator architectures are really good at stepping down the voltage by a large amount but are rather noisy, while others can only step the voltage down by a small amount but are quiet. You might choose how to arrange things based on where things make use of their strengths the best.

Comment: Hrm, so in my case where 24V -> 10V and 24V -> 3.3V are both pretty well in the realm of a lot of SMPS circuits, I'm probably better off just regulating both from the 24V?

Comment: @flimsy Take a look around and what is available. It might simply come to down to what you're willing to spend or how many different brand lines of converters you are willing to learn how to use. Or you might find a multi-output converter IC you are willing to implement from scratch on a PCB. That would be ideal since the clocks would be synchronized. You never mentioned if you want a module or IC.

Answer (score 0):

This won't surprise you: it depends.

Sometimes it's easier to go directly, sometimes it's easier to work off an intermediate voltage. (This is often a function on how much voltage headroom you need for fast regulation, and whether the least voltage rail has low or high current draw compared to what's already on the intermediate rail)

Sometimes, one or the other would be easier, but is impossible, because you want to avoid the noise between these rails being correlated.

Most often, you're somewhere in between: if you both options are viable, geometry often dictates that you want to stick with one voltage rail for everything, and locally convert from that, as close as possible to the consumer. That simplifies design; which one of the voltage rails, whether it's an unregulated input or some intermediate voltage, will then again depend on where things are located, where it's convenient to produce the heat etc.